# Why is my glass material noisy and opaque instead of translucent?

Tags: rendering, glass

I have been following a youtube tutorial on creating a window glass material. In the tutorial the outcome is perfect but when I copy it the outcome is grainy glass which is opaque rather than translucent. I have tried turning the reflective and refractive caustics on and off both together and individually. But this at best only has minor effect.

[image: Window]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Blender messed up. After messing around for a while to no avail I closed blender. When I went back to it and reloaded the scene the glass was transparent and the graininess for the most part had gone. [image: glass]